# how to set div element to always be one third from left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element inside another div element like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner" style="width:50%;"> 
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

inner div now covers half of the width of container. 
I want to position my inner div so that it is 1/3 of the empty space from left and 2/3 from right.
In other words 1/6 of the width of the container from left and 2/6 from right.
I want the inner div to be always like that even if you resize container. How do I do it?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mg8bmbme/?

Comment: Ok maybe his ^ math is correct, either way margin-left works even if you resize it.

Comment: You could simply use left/right margins like so `margin-left: 16.667%; margin-right: 33.333%;` without specifying the width. **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/piton/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#inner {
    margin-left: 16%;
}
```

Comment: You have no explanation here at all.

Answer (score 1):

Restricting both left and right margins with relative values (percentages) in my preferred approach so that any viewport changes are honored - as opposed to having just the left margin defined or using padding and affecting inner content.

```
#container {
  border: 1px solid red
}

#inner {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 20px 60% 20px 30%;
}
```

[Example via JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zacc206/yct26rd6/)

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left:16%` should work

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px;height:200px;background-color:#CCC">
  <div id="inner" style="width:50%;background-color:#555;margin-left:16%"> 
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Example here: http://jsbin.com/somapagujawi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try with css padding, like that :

```
#container {  
    border : 1px solid red;  
    padding : 10px 30% 10px 10%;  
}  
#inner {  
    border : 1px solid green;
}
```